# Bootstrap Alert will toggle between .show() after .hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

[Bootply Link](http://www.bootply.com/Hxn9E5njS6)

So the test link works, then when after you click the `x`, you can not toggle it back on without refreshing the page. What am I doing wrong?!

**Alert HTML**

```
<div class="alert alert-dismiss" id='alert' style="margin-top: 54px; margin-bottom: -54px;">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
    <div class='alertMessage'></div>
</div>
```

**Alert JS:**

```
$(function(){
    $('#updateAlert').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "update_alert.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#alert").addClass(data.statusClass);
                $(".alertMessage").html(data.responseMessage);
                $(".alert").show();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
$(".close").click(function(){
    $(".alert").hide();
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.alert').hide();
});
```

Comment: it is working:http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/hUGLn/

Comment: It isn't working in Bootstrap 3 for some reason.

Comment: Figured out the `data-dismiss="alert"` was causing the problems

Comment: If there's a better way to handle this rather than just removing the data-dismiss in Bootstrap, I'm open for advise. But for now I'm just removing it and using straight JS since it's a small snippet of JS anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bootstrap Alert jQuery plugin [removes the Alert from the DOM when you close the Alert](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/9096c2002123a6dafdf0c3d9df5d069c968d738e/js/alert.js#L50). That's how it works (intentionally).

If you don't want that, you can either not use `data-dismiss="alert"` or `$(...).alert('close')`, or you can modify the plugin yourself so that it behaves differently.

Comment: that makes sense, I want it to close / hide not remove. not using the data-dismiss at all works for me.